# Soundcloud record flash plugin don't work with current version of chrome under macOS

Tags: soundcloud

this record plugin stops to work for us with current version of chrome under macOS

Chrome: Version 23.0.1271.97

MacOS: 10.8.2

http://connect.soundcloud.com/examples/recording.html

#### how to reproduce:

1. click record
2. allow using your microphone
3. -> recording don't start

(In fact sometimes it works (20% of cases for me))
and also sometimes there is an error in console

```
PepperFlashPlayer.plugin: 0x2A052 is not valid resource ID.
```

Please help us, we use it for production and a lot of users can not record sound

regards, Dmitry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My investigation show:
sometimes the "SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA" event not triggered (or not assigned) in flash.

To solve this issue I do:

Added to event handler "StatusEvent.STATUS" (or call manually if microphone unmuted):

```
tti = setInterval(applySampleData, 100);
```

Added function:

```
protected function applySampleData() : void {
  microphone.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, recordSampleDataHandler);
  microphone.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, recordSampleDataHandler);
}
```

And in function "recordSampleDataHandler" (it's SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA listener):

```
if(tti) { clearInterval(tti); tti = 0; }
```

Try this.

Comment: Alexey! You save all us! Viva flash genius